# Survey doesn't allow administrator to subscribe for alerts

Tags: alert, survey

I have a SharePoint survey where users can respond and see their own replies. Administrators can see all replies but when I want to make an alert me for an administrator, I receive the following error:

> You cannot create alerts for list for which users can only read their
>   own items

Answer (score 1):

That is the standard SharePoint behaviour. The reasoning behind it is that a user setting up an alert would only be alerted to items that they created themselves.  In this case it is unfortunate that it also applies to administrators of the site, but that's how it is.

As a workaround, you can create a workflow in SharePoint Designer that sends an email to the administrator whenever an item is created (or changed).

Comment: too bad..because workflow dont wotk on survey as I read.

Comment: You could use a regular list and create the survey look and feel by customizing the list form with InfoPath.

Answer (score 1):

Alerts don't work, this is how it is in SharePoint so you can do the same thing in at least two ways.

In this case you can use **RSS-feed** instead.